# Game of Life: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SITUATION:**

I create a few dots and click on Start. The error pops a million times (logical since there are 100 cells and a setInterval).

---

**ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at Object.isAlive (main.js:21496)
    at Object.life (main.js:21533)
    at setInterval (main.js:21508)
```

---

**QUESTION:**

What is causing the error and how do I fix it ?

---

**GAME OF LIFE:**

[image]

---

**CODE:**

```
var Cell = createReactClass ({

getInitialState() {
    return {
        selected : false,
        dying: true,
        started: false,
    }
},

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    nextProps.array[nextProps.column][nextProps.row] = this;

    var evolution;

    if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {
        let evolution = setInterval(() => { 
            this.life(nextProps);
            console.log("DYING:"+this.state.dying);
            this.setState({
                selected: !this.state.dying
            });
        }, 500);
        this.setState({
            started: true,
            evolution
        })
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(this.state.evolution);
        this.setState({
            started: false
        })
    }
},

isAlive(e) {
    return (e.state.selected);
},

life(nextProps) {

    var array = nextProps.array;

    var neighbours = 0;

    var i = this.props.column;
    var j = this.props.row;
    var x = 40;
    var y = 40;

    if(this.isInBoard(i, j, x, y)) {
        if(this.isInBoard(i + 1, j, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i+1][j])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i - 1, j, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i-1][j])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i, j + 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i][j+1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i, j - 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i][j-1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i - 1, j + 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i-1][j+1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i + 1, j - 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i+1][j-1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i + 1, j + 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i+1][j+1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
        if(this.isInBoard(i - 1, j - 1, x, y)) {
            if (this.isAlive(array[i-1][j-1])) {
                neighbours++;
            }
        }
    }



    if (this.state.selected) {
        console.log("SELECTED!");
        if (neighbours == 3 || neighbours == 2) {
            this.setState({
                dying: false
            })
        }
        else if (neighbours < 2) {
            this.setState({
                dying: true
            })
        }
        else if (neighbours > 3) {
            this.setState({
                dying: true
            })
        }
    }
    else {
        if( neighbours == 3) {
            this.setState({
                dying : false
            })
        }
    }
},

isInBoard( i, j, x, y) {
    var flag = false;
    if (i >= 0 && i <= x && j >= 0 && j <= y) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag; 
},

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        selected: !this.state.selected
    })
},

render() {
    return <td onClick = {this.handleClick} className={this.state.selected ? "cell selected" : "cell"}></td>;
}
```

})

**Also:**

```
var Board = createReactClass ({

getInitialState() {
    var cellArray = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
        var cells = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            cells.push(<Cell key={x + y*40} id = {x + y*40} row = {x} column={y} />);
        }
        cellArray.push(cells);
    }
    return {
        array: cellArray
    }
},

render() {

    var rows = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
        var cells = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
            cells.push(<Cell start= {this.props.start} array={this.state.array} key={x + y*40} id = {x + y*40} column ={x} row={y} />);
        }
        rows.push(<tr key={y}>{cells}</tr>);
    }
    return <table><tbody>{rows}</tbody></table>;

}
```

})

```
var Game = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            start: false
        }
    },

    handleStartClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: true
        })
    },

    handleClearClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: false
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React.js Game of Life</h1>
                <div className="buttons"> 
                    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClearClick}>Clear</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleStartClick}>Start</button>
                </div>
                <Board start={this.state.start}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

})
```

Comment: It sounds like something is not passing correctly in isAlive... what do you see on `e`?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca `undefined`

Comment: what is the contents of `this.state.array`? I don't see it getting set... is it supposed to be the component references?

Comment: @BradBumbalough In the Board class, I set it in the getInitialState, then it gets updated in the WillReceiveProps of Cell.jsx

Comment: Why are you rendering a new array in Board instead of using the `state.array`?

Comment: @BradBumbalough Because I had to add the html tags (<tr>) ? (I am new to React, how would you use state.array) ?

Comment: Well I mean you're creating `cells` in render, but shouldn't that be your `state.array`? so iterate through this.state.array to return the cells within the correct tags. Not the issue, but I think it would mean the state is off.

Comment: @BradBumbalough Could you please put that in answer so I can see how it looks like ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're referencing `state` on a component, but it's not through a 'ref' to the component instance, so you won't have state. I think you'd want to look into [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). Have you tried logging what's getting passed to `isAlive`?

Since this seems more like a learning app than a real project, I'd advise spending more time learning React components and [thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) before posting every bug... we're willing to help but can't do the work for you :)

Welcome to React and I wish you the best of luck!

Comment: I understand ! Thanks for trying !

Comment: I made some progress, but now I really am stuck. Could you please have a look ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43564548/react-js-game-of-life-why-do-all-my-cells-disappear (I include a 50 rep bounty if we are able to make it work :D)