# Parent state not updating child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SITUATION:**

When I launch the simulation by clicking on Start, my Clear button is supposed to stop it. But when I click on Clear, nothing happens. Why and how do I fix it ?

---

**CODE:**

Game.jsx

```
var Game = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            start: false
        }
    },

    handleStartClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: true
        })
    },

    handleClearClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: false
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React.js Game of Life</h1>
                <div className="buttons"> 
                    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleClearClick}>Clear</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleStartClick}>Start</button>
                </div>
                <Board start={this.state.start}/>
            </div>
        );
    }

})
```

Board.jsx

```
var Board = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        var cellArray = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
            var cells = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
                cells.push(<Cell key={x + y*40} id = {x + y*40} row = {x} column={y} />);
            }
            cellArray.push(cells);
        }
        return {
            array: cellArray
        }
    },

    render() {

        var rows = [];
        for (var y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
            var cells = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < 40; x++) {
                cells.push(<Cell start= {this.props.start} array={this.state.array} key={x + y*40} id = {x + y*40} row = {x} column={y} />);
            }
            rows.push(<tr key={y}>{cells}</tr>);
        }
        return <table><tbody>{rows}</tbody></table>;

    }

})
```

Cell.jsx

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        nextProps.array[nextProps.id] = this;

        var evolution;

        if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {
            evolution = setInterval(() => { 
                this.life(nextProps);
                console.log("DYING:"+this.state.dying);
                this.setState({
                    selected: !this.state.dying
                });
            }, 500);
            this.setState({
                started: true
            })
        } 
        else {
            clearInterval(evolution);
            this.setState({
                started: false
            })
        }
    },
```

Comment: `my Clear button is supposed to stop it` is it stopping? Are you getting any errors in console.?

Comment: @Panther No errors, doesn't stop it.

Comment: You redefine `evolution` in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Keep it as `this.evolution`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your evolution interval to state so you can access it when the new props come in to cancel it.

```js
if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {
    let evolution = setInterval(() => { 
        this.life(nextProps);
        console.log("DYING:"+this.state.dying);
        this.setState({
            selected: !this.state.dying
        });
    }, 500);
    this.setState({
        started: true,
        evolution
    })
}
else {
    clearInterval(this.state.evolution);
    this.setState({
        started: false
    })
}
```

Comment: Perfect, it worked ! It seems you know reactsj well, would you be able to also have a look at this other question please ?  :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545989/game-of-life-cannot-read-property-state-of-undefined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545989/game-of-life-cannot-read-property-state-of-undefined

Comment: Great! sure I'll have a look.

Comment: I updated the question 1 minute ago with my latest advancements in the code just so you don't look at the old code.