# React.js Game of Life: Why doesn't the glider behave as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**SITUATION GIF:**

[image]

---

**SITUATION:**

No errors at all. I put some cells in, click start, they all disappear regardless of configuration. I also tried the glider configuration, it just disappears immediately.

If you find what I did wrong and we are able to make the Game of Life work, I will give you a 50 rep bounty on top of the accepted answer.

---

**UPDATE:**

Now, I can put dots and they will evolve but not as should be the case in the Game of Life. For example, see what happens with a glider configuration.

Here is how the Glider should behave:

[image]

Here is what happens:

[image]

More on the Glider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_(Conway%27s_Life)

---

**CODE:**

**Game**

```
var Game = createReactClass({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            start: false
        }                    
    },

    handleStartClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: true
        })
    },

    handleStopClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: false
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React.js Game of Life</h1>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handleStopClick}>Stop</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleStartClick}>Start</button>
                </div>
                <Board start={this.state.start}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

**Board**

```
var Board = createReactClass({

    getInitialState() {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            array.push(<Cell key={i} id={i} cells={array} start={this.props.start} />);
        }

        return {
            cells: array             
        };            
    },

    render() {

        var that = this;

        return (
            <div className="board">
                {
                    this.state.cells.map(function(item, i) {
                        return <Cell key={i} id={i} cells={that.state.cells} start={that.props.start}/>
                    })
                } 
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

**Cell**

```
var Cell = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            alive: false,
            nextAlive: false,
            started: false
        }                      
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        var evolution;

        if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {

            let evolution = setInterval(() => { 
                this.life();
                this.nextLife();
            }, 500);
            this.setState({
                started: true,
                evolution
            })   
        }

        else {
            clearInterval(this.state.evolution);
            this.setState({
                started: false
            })
        }

    },

    isAlive(r, c){

        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)

        if (r == -1) {
            r = size - 1
        }
        if (r == size) {
            r = 0
        }
        if (c == -1) {
            c = size - 1
        }
        if (c == size) {
            c = 0
        }
        var id = r * size + c
        return this.props.cells[id].state.alive

    },

    life() {

        var neighbours = 0
        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)
        var row = Math.floor( this.props.id / size )
        var col = this.props.id - row * size 

        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col)) {
            neighbours ++
        } 
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours ++
        }   
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col - 1))  {
            neighbours ++   
        }

        this.state.nextState = false 

        if (this.state.alive){
          if( neighbours < 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })
          }
          if (neighbours > 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })    
          }
          if (neighbours == 3 || neighbours == 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })
          }
        }
        else{
          if (neighbours == 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })   
          }
        }
    },

    nextLife () {
        this.setState({
            alive: this.state.nextAlive
        })     
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.cells[this.props.id] = this;
    },

    toggleLife() {
        this.setState({
            alive: !this.state.alive
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
           <div className={this.state.alive ? "cell alive" : "cell"} onClick={this.toggleLife}></div>
        );
    } 

});
```

Comment: What is this doing `this.state.nextState = false`? this should be in a `setState` and not mutated directly.. probably not the problem. It might be worth putting this in a Codepen so we could play with it.

Comment: This is also a bad pattern.... `this.props.cells[this.props.id] = this;` You can't mutate prop state.

Comment: Honestly I would `console.log` the wazoo out of this and see where the disconnect is happening.

Comment: I think what you need to do is keep the attributes of the cells in the boards state, not the components. So don't keep an array of `<Cell/>` in your state, keep the data and inject into `<Cell/>` in render method. Then, us a generic update function passed into the child components to update that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer your update separately.

Your next bug is more tricky: you update the cells independently without any synchronization. That means that depending on your luck, neighbors may be in completely different generation. Therefore what you get when you hit start is random.

In order to solve this problem, you need to move the ruling code to the `Board` element this way:

```
var Board = React.createClass({

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { // <- from here ...

    var evolution;

    if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {

      let evolution = setInterval(() => {
        this.state.cells.forEach( cell => cell.life() )
        this.state.cells.forEach( cell => cell.nextLife() )
      }, 500);

      this.setState({
        started: true,
        evolution
      })
    }

    else {
      clearInterval(this.state.evolution);
      this.setState({
        started: false
      })
    }

  }, // <- ... to here

  getInitialState() {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
      array.push(<Cell key={i} id={i} cells={array} start={this.props.start} />);
    }

    return {
      cells: array,
      started: false
    };
  },

  render() {

    var that = this;

    return (
      <div className="board">
      {
        this.state.cells.map(function(item, i) {
          return <Cell key={i} id={i} cells={that.state.cells} start={that.props.start}/>
        })
      }
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Then you should remove `componentWillReceiveProps()` from the cells element:

```
var Cell = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            alive: false,
            nextAlive: false,
            started: false
        }                      
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { /* I'm useless now */  },

    isAlive(r, c){

        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)

        if (r == -1) {
            r = size - 1
        }
        if (r == size) {
            r = 0
        }
        if (c == -1) {
            c = size - 1
        }
        if (c == size) {
            c = 0
        }
        var id = r * size + c
        return this.props.cells[id].state.alive

    },

    life() {

        var neighbours = 0
        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)
        var row = Math.floor( this.props.id / size )
        var col = this.props.id - row * size 

        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col)) {
            neighbours ++
        } 
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours ++
        }   
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col - 1))  {
            neighbours ++   
        }

        this.state.nextState = false 

        if (this.state.alive){ // bug 2
          if( neighbours < 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })
          }
          if (neighbours > 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })    
          }
          if (neighbours == 3 || neighbours == 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })
          }
        }
        else{
          if (neighbours == 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })   
          }
        }
    },

    nextLife () {
        this.setState({
            alive: this.state.nextAlive
        })     
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.cells[this.props.id] = this;
    },

    toggleLife() {
        this.setState({
            alive: !this.state.alive
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
           <div className={this.state.alive ? "cell alive" : "cell"} onClick={this.toggleLife}></div>
        );
    } 

});
```

As a side note you can also remove the `started` state and the `start` props from `Cell` too.

Comment: What can I say :D You are the best !  I need to wait 12 hours to award the bounty, but you already earned it !

Comment: You're welcome :) Enjoy react. Next you can take a look at redux and connect to simplify a bit your code.

Comment: I looked at Redux, but felt I should first grasp a bit better React :D Merci!

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is probably not where you were looking at. In the `Cell` component's `componentWillReceiveProps` function:

```
if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {

    let evolution = setInterval(() => { 
        this.life();
        this.nextLife();
    }, 500);
    this.nextLife(); // <- remove this line !!
    this.setState({
        started: true,
        evolution
    })   
}
```

You should remove the `this.nextLife()` (or call `this.life()` before).
Indeed, this function sets `alive` to `nextAlive` before it to be computed by `nextLife()`: in other words you set to its default value, that is, `false`.

By the way, I spotted another bug in the `life()` function of the cell component: you access to `this.state.selected` instead of `this.state.alive`.

In conclusion the code of your `Cell` component should be:

```
var Cell = createReactClass ({

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            alive: false,
            nextAlive: false,
            started: false
        }                      
    },

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

        var evolution;

        if(nextProps.start && this.state.started == false) {

            let evolution = setInterval(() => { 
                this.life();
                this.nextLife();
            }, 500);
            // this.nextLife(); // bug 1
            this.setState({
                started: true,
                evolution
            })   
        }

        else {
            clearInterval(this.state.evolution);
            this.setState({
                started: false
            })
        }

    },

    isAlive(r, c){

        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)

        if (r == -1) {
            r = size - 1
        }
        if (r == size) {
            r = 0
        }
        if (c == -1) {
            c = size - 1
        }
        if (c == size) {
            c = 0
        }
        var id = r * size + c
        return this.props.cells[id].state.alive

    },

    life() {

        var neighbours = 0
        var size = Math.sqrt(this.props.cells.length)
        var row = Math.floor( this.props.id / size )
        var col = this.props.id - row * size 

        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row - 1, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col + 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row, col - 1)) {
            neighbours++
        }
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col)) {
            neighbours ++
        } 
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col + 1)) {
            neighbours ++
        }   
        if (this.isAlive(row + 1, col - 1))  {
            neighbours ++   
        }

        this.state.nextState = false 

        if (this.state.alive){ // bug 2
          if( neighbours < 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })
          }
          if (neighbours > 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: false 
              })    
          }
          if (neighbours == 3 || neighbours == 2) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })
          }
        }
        else{
          if (neighbours == 3) {
              this.setState ({
                 nextAlive: true 
              })   
          }
        }
    },

    nextLife () {
        this.setState({
            alive: this.state.nextAlive
        })     
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.cells[this.props.id] = this;
    },

    toggleLife() {
        this.setState({
            alive: !this.state.alive
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
           <div className={this.state.alive ? "cell alive" : "cell"} onClick={this.toggleLife}></div>
        );
    } 

});
```

Comment: Making progress ! Great ! Please have a look at my update. Have an upvote in the mean time

Comment: Would you know the answer to this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612477/how-to-generate-a-random-starting-position-for-the-game-of-life